Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath' for kotlin
I was trying to put firebase in my project and then I was following a video, then this happened.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom


at first it said that I need a newer version of kotlin and so I changed the version then that happened
I tried to change some codes but it doesn't work
this is the android build gradle code
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1"
    }
}

this is the dependencies in app build gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}


and my plugins
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"


1.7.1 was withdrawn, probably due to CVEs discovered in it. Try a newer version like 1.7.22 (that itself is very out of date being nearly two years old).

There is no version 1.7.1 of the Kotlin plugin, hence the reason for your error.
1.7.10 is available, the last 1.7.x version was 1.7.22, or the latest stable is 1.9.23. Note the version is a string, so these things matter.
Also, you use the Kotlin version hard-coded in this line:
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1"

when you probably meant to write
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

and use the version variable you've defined.
